# Search record in HABTM relationship - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a stores and store_details table and now a store_details_stores table.

The Store model has the following:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('StoreDetail');
```

The StoreDetail model has the following:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Store');
```

When I attempt the below query in the stores_controller, I receive an sql error. For some reason the store_details table is not being joined naturally. Is this expected behaviour? Do I need to join this table manually?

```
$this->Store->find('all', array('conditions' => array('StoreDetail.name' => 'Parking')));
```

Comment: Posting the SQL+Cake error and the query log would be definitely helpful.

Comment: It's giving an SQL error because StoreDetail is not being joined, so StoreDetail.name does not exist. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. You need to set up a bindModel call with your conditions, or you can create a model for your join table and query that directly.

See:

[CakePHP Book - HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM)

[Modelizing HABTM Join Tables](http://marianoiglesias.com.ar/cakephp/modelizing-habtm-join-tables-in-cakephp-1-2-with-and-auto-with-models/)

```
$this->Store->bindModel(array(
    'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
            'StoreDetail' => array('conditions'=>array('StoreDetail.name' => 'Parking')
))));
$this->Store->find('all');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend applying the condition to the association before you do your find, using the **bindModel** method.

```
/**
 * Apply a condition to the association
 */
$this->Store->bindModel(array(
    'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
        'StoreDetail' => array('conditions' => array('StoreDetail.name'=>'Parking'))
)));

/**
 * Find all Stores that have an associated StoreDetail.name of 'Parking'
 */
$this->Store->find('all');
```